# Datebase-comparing tool that supports schema and data

Tags: diff, sql

I'm looking for a tool which is able to compare schema as well as data of a database. Ideally for some Sybase SQLAnywhere. All what I've found was only for schema.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/), which is ideally suited to this purpose. SchemaCrawler can generate human-readable database schema and data "snapshots", which are designed to be compared using plain-text file comparison (that is, standard diff) tools. SchemaCrawler is database and operating system independent, free, open-source, and can be invoked from the command-line, as well as through a Java API.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)