# Free command line tool to find schema (and data) differences between 2 SQL Server databases

Tags: database, command-line

I have [posted this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308927/sql-server-schema-compare-via-nunit-and-use-of-scmp-file) and while the solution posted works I am still on the hunt for a simple **command line** (don't need a GUI as this is for automation purposes) utility that does 2 basic things:

1. Tell me schema differences
2. Tell me data differences

While there are MANY SO posts (and I have read them all) on the subject most of them either list commercial tools (RedGate in particular) or are very old posts (like 7+ years old) and the software does not exist.

There are a couple of interesting Microsoft solutions to this:

1. [TableDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms162843.aspx)
2. [VsDBCmd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx#comparewithvsdbcmd)

The issues with TableDiff are that it was built for replication so even though the tables are identical in schema it will report even if the columns are in a DIFFERENT order - it was meant for low level stuff. So hence heaps of false positives.

VsDBCmd requires an installation of Visual Studio on the machine doing the comparison. As this is for CI automation purposes this is not a solution in my case. I want something simple and self contained.

So has anyone got any tool that they have seen or can recommend that can do the basics (as stated above):

- Free
- Command Line
- Self Contained
- Compare Schema
- Compare Data

All pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Any smart database schema comparison tools?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18366/185) / **[Tool for database comparison](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4146/185)** (SQLServer, free – it's almost a dupe) / [Datebase-comparing tool that supports schema and data](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13255/185)